# Can I warn people?

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, rules

When users ask bad questions (often new contributors), can I warn them? What I mean is whenever I see a situation like this, usually a user with a high reputation comments on a question. Something like

> Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this or that to ask a proper question or to learn proper question format

Can every user warn new contributors or is there some kind of rule for that?

Comment: Sure, why not?, you'll even see low rep users reminding high rep users of that sometimes

Comment: Note that saying _welcome to Stack Overflow_ to long-term users is dubious and could be considered rude

Comment: I suggest to add some details on what the user should improve. Just a generic "you did something wrong, read the rules" comment might not be a good idea.

Comment: Be sure to spell the name of the site correctly -- it's "Stack Overflow", two words.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Although it is a very unnatural spelling, especially considering the Stack Overflow logo, we would really appreciate if you, at your earliest convenience, started using [the official spelling](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance).

Comment: I tend to copy the "Please ..." that comes as an aside note of the flag I raise, also minding to copy the right links to the relevant tour / MCVE / How to ask page. This way I am sure that I don't get called about using some bad wording that would go against the code of conduct.

Comment: Just use the `[so]` magic link, save yourself some typing, and get the officially correct spelling for free!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Certainly, you may communicate with any OP (= "original poster") about their question.

In such cases, however, I would not think about this as a "warning". Instead, consider how to best *guide* the person about how to optimally use the site / ask a question in order to get a good reception for it and an answer.

The way you're thinking when you start communicating with someone affects their perception of what you write. Usually, it helps when guiding to be non-confrontational...

Answer (score 22):

Comments are fraught with "Welcome Wagon" problems.  Anything you say can potentially be interpreted as a slight or unwelcoming.  My advice?  Let the system work instead.  Cast your close vote without comment, and move on.

New users *already have a wealth of information to draw from.*  They have the Help Center, FAQ posts on Meta, and the Question Asking Wizard.  They can lurk for awhile and watch other people's posts, see how the community reacts to them.

I've watched this play out for many years, and my sincere belief is that you are better off registering feedback with close votes and delete votes and declining from commenting.  There are simply too many ways that comments can go wrong.

Reserve your comments solely for post clarification.  That is their only sanctioned use.

Comment: Close votes are about 1900 rep point away from OP

Comment: Then flag it instead.  IIRC, for low-rep users the system will display the usual close vote dialog, and will place the post into a review queue.

Comment: "*a "phantom" close vote*" just for clarity, that is called a flag.

Comment: Yep, you have to be careful or the _Welcome Wagon_ may run over you. But, generally posting whole text from appropriate close reason should not cause any problems, especially if you don't get involved in further explanations.

Comment: This is sad. Can't we help people try to improve?

Comment: @jl2210: Not without further politicizing the platform.  I'll write a further clarification.

Answer (score 9):

They write a comment to OP.
Comments are a privilege at 50 rep points.
You have about 13 times more than that in rep points.

I can't see a reason why you should not write helpful comments that help the community.

Comment: *I can't see a reason why you should not write helpful comments that help the community.* Biggest reason is it makes you a target.  You tell them what they did wrong, someone down votes, now they blame you, since you were nice enough to point out that the post has issues.

Comment: @NathanOliver completely depends on how you deliver such message. If you write a well formulated comment explaining what is wrong with the post and how to correct it, it's usually well received too. And since it's generally new users, they are not allowed to downvote yet. I don't think I have been downvoted because of any of my comments I have posted that was in a helpful manner as this is. But if I have, who cares?